# Meaning of 앞으로 남고 뒤로 밑지다

Tags: vocabulary

'앞으로 벌고 뒤로 손해본다'라고도 표현되는 것 같던데 현재 값어치/현금 유동성과 관련된 말인 것 같습니다만 정확히 어떤 의미로 쓰이는지 해석 부탁드립니다. 감사합니다.

It seems to have something to do with the time value of money, but I can't wrap my head around it. Will appreciate explaining on what it stands for exactly. Thank you.

Specific focus is on the phrase 앞으로 남고 뒤로 밑지다 in the context given above.

Comment: Hi @Vladhagen, my apologies for bothering you. There's something I would like to consult you privately to address an issue that I have. Would it be possible for you to reach out to me privately via inbox messages? I'd be enormously grateful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

겉으로 보기에는 돈을 버는 것 같지만, 실제적으론 돈을 버는 것이 아니라 손해인 경우를 의미합니다. (Superficially it looks like great benefit at the point of the money, But in fact it is deficit.)

Example) Mr. kim has the big store. He make money 100 million dollars per month. But He must pay tax to the goverment and salary to his employees etc. Total expenditure is 110 million dollars. On the face of it Mr kim earned a lot of money, But in fact He is in the deficit pratically. In this case "앞으로 남고 뒤로 밑지다."